# How to sort List<File> to list directories first and grouping files by directory?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, apache-commons, comparator

In order to get all files contained in a specified directory and according to some extensions, I'm using the method [`listFiles`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter)) of class [`FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library, as in the following code sample.

```
ArrayList<String> wildcards = new ArrayList<>();
wildcards.add("*.cpp");
wildcards.add("*.h");
wildcards.add("*.txt");

File dir = new File("/path/to/dir");
Collection<File> found = FileUtils.listFiles(
        dir,
        new WildcardFileFilter(wildcards, IOCase.SENSITIVE),
        DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);

List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(found);
```

The order of items in the resulting `Collection<File>` varies in the different operating systems, so I would sort them (ie. the wrapping list `files`) in according to the following rules.

- The directories should be listed before the files.
- The sorting routine should group files by directory.

Example:

```
/path/to/dir/first/subpath/main.cpp
/path/to/dir/first/subpath/utils.cpp
/path/to/dir/first/subpath/utils.h
/path/to/dir/first/main.cpp
/path/to/dir/first/utils.cpp
/path/to/dir/first/utils.h
/path/to/dir/second/main.cpp
/path/to/dir/second/utils.cpp
/path/to/dir/second/utils.h
/path/to/dir/README.txt
```

Comment: Sorting the files by their full path name should do the trick, doesn't it?

Comment: @ammoQ: unfortunately no, because for example `/path/to/dir/README.txt` would be less than `/path/to/dir/second/utils.h`, if I sort them by their full path name.

Comment: Well, it depends whether you think about `README.txt` as a leaf child of the `dir` node that comes before the `second` node or not. If you want to have directories first, it's not the same as depth-first, exactly.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: well, ok, it should works as you said, but I was not able to explain the concept in the title, so I reported the above example :)

Comment: It seems you want to display, perhaps, the deepest path first, and then less deep paths? And what happens when you have paths of equal depths? Which comes first? Note that this is *not* depth-first search.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: The files should be shown in an order that reflects the recursive listing of the directory. When I have paths of equal depths, they should be sorted by their path names.

Comment: I think you have a misconception of how the recursive listing of a directory works. It usually is a depth-first search, but its order is determined by the ordering of nodes inside each directory, which is undetermined unless you set up a specific search order such as time or name. If you want something which is *not* a depth-first search, you need to define it properly.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: well, actually that's true, so I will add some details to the question to better explain the sorting rules.

Comment: You can use one of these comparators in apache-common-io lib: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/comparator/package-summary.html.
Try DefaultFileComparator or DirectoryFileComparator or PathFileComparator or composite comparator of few of them - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/comparator/CompositeFileComparator.html

Comment: So in your comparison routine, sort by the path (without the filename), and then by filename if the paths are equal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java 8's `stream`s to solve your problem. Something like this should work:

```
//untested
Map<Path, List<Path>> dirToFileMap = files.stream()
            .map(f -> Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Path::getParent));
```

With that map you can achieve what you need. Iterate over `keySet` first, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Just a matter of typing; below I do not take canonical paths (Windows is case-insensitive), but the gist is clear.

So a `Comparator` for sorting:

```
public class FileComparator extends Comparator<File> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(File lhs, File rhs) {
        if (lhs == null && rhs == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (lhs == null || rhs == null) {
            return lhs == null ? -1 : 1;
        }
        int cmp = compareTo(lhs.getParentFile(), rhs.getParentFile());
        if (cmp == 0) {
            if (lhs.isDirectory() != rhs.isDirectory()) {
                return lhs.isDirectory() ? -1 : 1;
            }
            cmp = lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
        }
        return cmp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object comparator) {
        return comparator != null && comparator.getClass().equals(getClass());
    }
}
```

As always the `equals` just compares comparators, not Files.

Answer (score 1):

After an entire afternoon of scratching my head at this, here's what worked for me:

```java
files.sort((p1, p2) -> pathToStr(p1).compareToIgnoreCase(pathToStr(p2)));
files.forEach(System.out::println); //They'll be ordered now!

//A method I wrote for pulling this off
public static String pathToStr(File path) {
    boolean isDir = path.isDirectory();
    String str = path.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/").replace("/", "/\0");
    if (!isDir) {
        int idx = str.lastIndexOf("/\0");
        str = str.substring(0, idx) + str.substring(idx, str.length()).replace("/\0", "/");
    }
    return str;
}
```

So basically, what `pathToStr()` does is making a string representation of a file path, but with a twist: all folder names in the path will have a null `\0` character prepended. This way, the stock string ordering will push all subfolders to the top of each folder. It should work fine as long as you don't have any file names starting with a null char, which I don't think is even possible due to how good old C handles strings.

As an additional note, if you want to order things in a more Unix-like fashion, you can change that `compareToIgnoreCase` to just `compareTo`, in order to consider different casing.

This question may be kind of old (5 years old at the moment I'm writing this), but I couldn't find any answers that would not involve using libraries or mixing several comparators, so once I figured it out I decided to come back here and add my two cents. Enjoy your saved afternoon.

**Edit:** Since the question does not use NIO paths, I had to change my code to an alternative version using only `File`; but in case you're using NIO paths like me, here's the code I'm using:

```java
List<Path> items = Files.walk(rootFolder).collect(Collectors.toList());
items.sort((p1, p2) -> pathToStr(p1).compareToIgnoreCase(pathToStr(p2)));
items.forEach(System.out::println); //They'll be ordered now!

public static String pathToStr(Path path) {
    boolean isDir = Files.isDirectory(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    String str = path.toAbsolutePath().toString().replace("\\", "/").replace("/", "/\0");
    if (!isDir) {
        int idx = str.lastIndexOf("/\0");
        str = str.substring(0, idx) + str.substring(idx, str.length()).replace("/\0", "/");
    }
    return str;
}
```

There we go, whether you're using NIO or not, this answer has you covered.

Comment: The question is 5 years old. I consider a nio solution to be the better approach in 2020.